# fragment in viewpager can't be programmed

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using a view pager in my app the view pager contains three layouts and I can swipe between them well and it shows me the different layout files but when I tried to use java orders on this layout I found that nothing changed in the layout for example I tried to change the text of a textView but I found that it hasn't changed

this is the main activity code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("posts");

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(this);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("تعلم");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.learn, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("الصفحة الرئيسية");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.home, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("التحديات");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.challenges, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

and this is the java code of the fragment :

```
 // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("posts");

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        etAddPost = myView.findViewById(R.id.etAddPost);
        TextView tv = myView.findViewById(R.id.testText);
        tv.setText("new text");
        addPostBtn(myView);
        return myView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
```

and this is the view pager adapter code :

```
 public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * @return the number of pages to display
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the value returned from {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)} is the
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

    /**
     * Return the title of the item at {@code position}. This is important as what this method
     * <p>
     * Here we construct one using the position value, but for real application the title should
     * refer to the item's contents.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = "";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                title = "تعلم";
                break;
            case 1:
                title = "الصفحة الرئيسية";
                break;
            case 2:
                title = "التحديات";
                break;
        }
        return title;
    }
    // END_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

    /**
     * Instantiate the {@link View} which should be displayed at {@code position}. Here we
     * inflate a layout from the apps resources and then change the text view to signify the position.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert li != null;
        View view = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                view = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn, container, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                view = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                view = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_challenges, container, false);
                break;
        }
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * {@link View}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

}
```

and this is the activity main xml code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/color1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_in_toolbar" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/color1">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post your `activity_main` layout code

Comment: I will edit my post now